Failed to convert atomikos J2eeTransactionManager to required type jakarta TransactionManager
I have a Java application that runs in Docker using Tomcat and Maven.
We are using docker-compose command to build/up the application. build works fine, but when I do the up an error is thrown:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core-infrastructure.xml]: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager' to required type 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager' to required type 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 126 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager' to required type 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager' to required type 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:609)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
        ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager' to required type 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' for property 'transactionManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
        ... 138 more
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [bitronix-task-scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep0(Native Method)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:509)
 bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler.run(TaskScheduler.java:245)

We use transaction manager XML configuration
<!-- Atomikos properties are set in jta.properties -->
<bean id="atomikosTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownWait">
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager" depends-on="atomikosTransactionService"/> 

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction"/> 

<!-- Spring JtaTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="${jta.transaction.default.timeout}"/>
</bean>

The funny part is that the application works for my other two colleagues.
I tried to make sure that the Maven dependencies are fine in Docker container and I even used docker volume rm [volume-name] and recreated everything, but it didn't fix the problem.
I compared my colleague's Maven dependencies from their Docker container with mine: Docker Desktop > click on container name > Exec Tab > write bash (you should be in Tomcat after) > cd webapps > cd ROOT > cd WEB-INF > cd lib > ls and they are exactly the same.
In this old post https://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default3c36.html?community.6.3158.2 is suggested to look for another transaction JAR that can cause conflicts. I'm trying to spot it.

The issue was generated by a conflict between these 2 libraries:
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
</dependency>

The solution was to exclude transactions-jta from hibernate3.
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
                <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
</dependency>

The application worked for my colleagues because their Maven picked the correct transactions-jta for them, but my Maven chose the Hibernate's one . This could be checked by running mvn dependency:tree (the library version that's closest to the top of the tree is chosen), but in our case we were not able to run mvn commands inside our Docker container.

You shouldn't be using transactions-hibernate3 but rather transactions-hibernate4 which is for Hibernate 6. Although I doubt you even need the transactions-hibernate3 library at all as you are using Spring to drive your transactions and not Hibernate. See https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ExtremeTransactions6dot0#Feature199608_Hibernate_6_support

@M.Deinum I wonder what kind of naming conventions leads the a library ending in hibernate4 to be for Hibernate 6...

If you do switch to transactions-hibernate4, you also need to make sure to add <classifier>jakarta</classifier>.
